# separate three NSStrings, how?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am joining three strings and in between of them "*" is putted,
now I want to separate three of them (Name, Email, Address), how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];
```

See the [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for more information.

Comment: Will it give me array having 3 strings?

Comment: @Veer Yes, each element in the array is an NSString. An example is given on the page I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [componentsSeparatedByString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) like this:

```
NSArray *seperated-strings = [yourstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];
```

That should give you an array with your three strings in it.

EDIT: Whoops, got beaten to it...

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that `*` characters are [allowed within email addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax), so you should consider using a more robust method to serialize your tuple. e.g. [JSON](http://www.json.org/)